# Macros work well in excel 2013 but not in 2007

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am using the following code

`Range("AI2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Table3[@[Column3]:[Column" & v & "]])"`

It does work fine in my system. However when I try running it on my company's system which has excel 2007, its giving a run time error.

Comment: To quote "All examples in this article are for Excel 2010 and later. There is a slight difference between using structured referencing in Excel 2010 and Excel 2007—Excel 2007 is not covered in this article. For the purposes of discussion, the traditional method of referencing cells (i.e. A1, A2, B1:B100, A2:D100, etc.) is referred to as standard referencing." [Reference is here](http://peltiertech.com/structured-referencing-excel-tables/). Perhaps this is the reason that Macros work well in excel 2013 but not in 2007. I have not recently used these references.

Comment: Another useful link [Using structured references with Excel tables
Applies To: Excel 2007](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e)

Comment: One example of difference in syntax in 2007 ~[#This Row]~ While in Excel 2010 It is ~@~

Comment: For Excel 2010 [Using structured references with Excel tables
Applies To: Excel 2010](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-a547e45e-3589-4417-b611-abb7e5d3f912)

Comment: Since I do not have Excel 2007 I can test for your problem. The following example clearly brings out syntax difference for structured reference between Excel 2007 & Excel 2010 ~MS Excel 2010 Formula:

=VLOOKUP(Table1[@LoanNumber], Table2[#All], MATCH(Table2[@Column10],Table2[@], 0), FALSE)

MS Excel 2007 Formula:
=VLOOKUP(Table1[[#This Row],[LoanNumber]], Table2[#All], MATCH(Table2[[#This Row],[Column10]],Table2[#This Row], 0), FALSE)~

Comment: @skkakkar Thanks man that work :)

Comment: Please accept it as an answer by ticking green tick mark below lower triangle on left side of the answer. This is one thing which you can only do. I am really glad that it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following for Excel 2007

```
   Range("AI2").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Table3[[#This Row],[Column3]]:[Column" & v & "]])"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@` syntax was only [introduced in Excel 2010](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2010/01/25/table-improvements-in-excel-2010.aspx), so Excel 2007 does not understand it. On the other hand the `[#This Row]` syntax was deprecated in Excel 2010 and gets [automatically replaced in multi -line tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-structured-references-in-Excel-table-formulas-75fb07d3-826a-449c-b76f-363057e3d16f):

> **`#This Row` or `@` or `@[Column Name]`**
>
> Just the cells in the same row as the formula. These specifiers can’t be combined with any other special item specifiers. Use them to force implicit intersection behavior for the reference or to override implicit intersection behavior and refer to single values from a column.
>
> Excel automatically changes `#This Row` specifiers to the shorter `@` specifier in tables that have more than one row of data. But if your table has only one row, Excel doesn’t replace the `#This Row` specifier, which may cause unexpected calculation results when you add more rows. To avoid calculation problems, make sure you enter multiple rows in your table before you enter any structured reference formulas.

You probably should use old-fashion `=SUM(A2:C2)` style references to make it compatible across multiple versions of Excel.